# Is my injection script removed by Ajax & history.pushState()?

Tags: ajax, code-injection

wrote a simple chrome extension which inject a real-time clock into tab page.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insert-timestamp/hojacnchclkfkdkcadnfogedeppclijb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

it works for most webpages, like google.com, yahoo.com, ebay.com,
but doesn't work for youtube.com.

And after searching I learned this could result from AJAX & history.pushState() which might remove the injected java scripts inside the DOM...

I do not know too much about this, may somebody help me to figure out a way to make the injected scripts work on youtube.com?
Thanks~!

Comment: At the time the script is loaded and/or evaluated it will _live_  in the document until the document is reloaded.  A `pushState` does not reload the page. As of that your script is still running, but what might happen is that your DOMElement that you created was removed after the page replaced its content with the requested data.

Comment: Could be like that, thanks. Is there any way to avoid my DOM element been removed...?

Comment: No. You need to observer your object e.g. with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or similar (don't know which technique ist currently supported in Chrome). And add it again yourself.